# Change microphone sensitivity in Steam

Tags: steam, technical-issues, counter-strike-global-offensive

I know that my headset's microphone is working fine because I use it in Skype talks, but everytime I want to play CSGO I need to scream so the other players can hear me.

I have already use it in Discord. I had the same problem. But I found a way to change my microphone sensitivity. Is there any way to change it in CSGO definitions or in Steam settings?

I've already google it, but I can't find any solution to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Steam has an option to set the microphone volume under **Settings > Voice:**

[image]

You can adjust the microphone volume and hit the test button and talk to check the level.

Comment: I've already tried that option, inclusive I tried to put the max volume, but the other players still can't hear me

Answer (score 0):

You can change the volume of your microphone in the sound setting of the Operating System. Assuming Windows, you have to get in the **Sound** interface and get in the **Recording** tab. Right click your microphone and select **Properties**. In the new window, you should have the **Levels** tab. In it, there will be a slider for the volume of your microphone.

[image: Microphone Volume in Windows]

Sorry about the language in the picture, my Windows is not in English.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you talk about  the automatic activation by sensibility steam and cs:go don't have it you need to use the push to talk function

For user don't hear you when you talk , check to be sure your default micrphone in windows is the one you use , because if you have a webcam or other microphone set it possible you use the wrong microphone

To check it

1-Right click on the speaker in your taskbar

2-click on "record device"

A windows like this one will open

[image]

check if your headset microphone have the green circle with the white check inside

if not select it and push "set default"

also like JMichelB said , check your microphone volume 
double click on it and go in "level".
Adjust your mic level, sometime you have a second level for the microphone boost or you can have an extra tabs for it , adjust it carefully or you will hurt everyone when you will talk