# How can I change microphone sensitivity in the newest Steam update

Tags: steam

The newest update removed the setting in steam to test and change sensitivity, and they also removed right clicking your profile pic in a call and adjusting it there. Does anyone know how to do it now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ability to test your microphone sensitivity within Steam appears to have been removed with the new User Interface update.  Previously, you were able to do this via following [these steps](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/321322/change-microphone-sensitivity-in-steam), but this is no longer the case.  You can however, still adjust the input and output volume of your microphone/headset.  You can do this by:

1. Open up your "Friends & Chat" window via clicking the text at the bottom right of the Steam client
2. On the window that pops-up, click the settings wheel in the top right, and select "Voice."
3. Find the Input volume/gain and Output volume/gain controls to adjust your input and output volume.

There is one setting within this same menu called "Voice Transmission Threshold," which I believe is the new way of adjusting your sensitivity.  There are three options for it, Off, Medium, and High.  Unfortunately, there still does not appear a way to test if the sensitivity is what you want after adjusting this control.

[image: Settings for Mic]
[image: Threshold control]